# igraph graph.data.frame silently converts factors to character vectors

Tags: r, igraph

Today I learned that igraph silently loses factors on graph.data.frame, so factors in the vertex data frame are converted to character vectors.  Is there a way to retain the factor type e.g. for `V(g)$factor_var` and `df <- get.data.frame(g, what="vertices"); df$factor_var`?  In the following code, `gender` is the `factor_var`:

```
actors <- data.frame(name=c("Alice", "Bob", "Cecil", "David", "Esmeralda"),
                     age=c(48,33,45,34,21),
                     gender=factor(c("F","M","F","M","F")))
relations <- data.frame(from=c("Bob", "Cecil", "Cecil", "David",
                               "David", "Esmeralda"),
                        to=c("Alice", "Bob", "Alice", "Alice", "Bob", "Alice"),
                        same.dept=c(FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE),
                        friendship=c(4,5,5,2,1,1), advice=c(4,5,5,4,2,3))
g <- graph.data.frame(relations, directed=TRUE, vertices=actors)
g_actors <- get.data.frame(g, what="vertices")

# Compare type of gender (before and after)
is.factor(actors$gender)
is.factor(g_actors$gender)
```

In this reproducible example, actors$gender is a factor but g_actors$gender is not.  In my opinion, it should be.  I found no comment about this issue in the documentation.

This is important because exporting vertices via `get.data.frame` for linear regression looses factors (linear regression converts factors to dummy variables, but ignores character vectors).  I noticed because my factor variables disappeared in the output.

Of course, I can recreate the factors after exporting from igraph, but this is tedious because I have a lot of graphs and the level ordering is all wrong (and I do not believe it should be necessary, unless igraph cannot support this behavior across its C++ and python versions).

Ryan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, `graph.data.frame` has

```
newval <- d[, i]
if (class(newval) == "factor") {
  newval <- as.character(newval)
}
attrs[[names(d)[i]]] <- newval
```

so it converts factors to characters. I am not sure why, but it has been there forever:
https://github.com/igraph/igraph/blame/c5849a89739c0dd058ff0a770aff2443745636fa/interfaces/R/igraph/R/structure.generators.R#L602

As a workaround, you can create a copy of the function, under a different name, and remove these three lines.

If you think that this is a bug, then please also open an issue at https://github.com/igraph/igraph/issues and I'll add an option not too convert. I think the default will still be to convert, just because it has been there for a long time, and people might rely on it.

Comment: Thanks Gabor.  For now I wrote a function to regenerate my factors.  Indeed many people rely on igraph, it is a great package!